# Passing parameters from table to view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to pass a parameter from a `UITableViewController` to a `ViewController`. This is the code i am using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ServiceViewNavigation"];

    ServiceTableView *serviceTable = [[ServiceTableView alloc]init];
    serviceTable.ID = [Service_ID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    serviceTable.Category = [Service_name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:serviceTable animated:YES];

    [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];
}
```

This looks so simple but it is not passing anything and when i `NSLog` ID in "serviceTable" i get (null).

Comment: is Your Service_ID has objects? What is Service Table View Class?

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov Service_ID is just an array thats not the matter! and serviceTable is a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make an method in viewController and the access that method in tableviewcontroller. And assign all values into that method. Like following.

ViewController.m

```
MenuList* menu = [[MenuList alloc] init];
[menu sendArray:array1:array2:arry3:array4];
```

MenuList.m

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *) sendArray:(NSArray *) array1:(NSArray *)array2:(NSArray *)array3:(NSArray *)array4;
{
//assign all array to your viewcontroller's array.
}
```